# Translating String with Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I want to Translate a String, with AngularJs filter and here i will put my code :

```
item={ "_id": "58b9ee5fd7835400059c11f7", "privilegeParent": "58b9ec296aca0e2020257c4a", "create": { "at": "2017-03-05T01:34:28.273Z" }, "notifications": { "web": { "active": false }, "mail": { "active": false }, "sms": { "active": false }, "parameters": [] }, "name": { "code": "systemStatus", "en": "System Status" } }
```

And here html code :

```
 <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools"><span>{{::"update_screen"| translate :'{x:item.name.en}'}}</span>
        </h2>
```

and Here Desired String "update_screen":"Update Screen of {{x}}"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using lodash, in your filter function you can do this:

```
function myFilter() {
    return function(str, obj) {
        return _.join(['Update screen of ', _.get(str, obj.x)]);   
    }
}
```

If you're not using any utility library, please provide a little more information

Hope that helps!